# requests_html render returns Access Denied

Tags: python, python-3.x

When trying to render a page using requests_html, I get access denied from the server. When I send via requests I get the HTML.

Why do I get access denied?

**Code**

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
s = HTMLSession()

base_url = 'https://secure.louisvuitton.com/eng-gb/checkout/review'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'TE': 'Trailers',
}

r = s.get('https://secure.louisvuitton.com/eng-gb/checkout/review', headers=headers)
print(r)


r.html.render()
print(r.html.text)
```

**Terminal**

```
<Response [200]>
Access Denied
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://secure.louisvuitton.com/eng-gb/checkout/review" on this server.
Reference #18.6fce7a5c.1597604631.1e8bfd7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this site doesn't like a headless browsers and it detects this from the `User-Agent` header. In my case it was:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) **HeadlessChrome**/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36

Now, the `requests_html` module is using [Pyppeteer](https://pyppeteer.github.io/pyppeteer/index.html) under the hood to render JavaScript. There is an option to set the UA for a [page](https://pyppeteer.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html?highlight=user%20agent#pyppeteer.browser.Browser.userAgent) in `Pyppeteer` but I don't see a convenient way to overwrite some class to make this change. The `page` is defined in [`_async_render`](https://github.com/psf/requests-html/blob/v0.10.0/requests_html.py#L505) function (a `coroutine` to be precise).

You can try to use `Pyppeteer` directly and then only parse the HTML using [`requests_html`](https://requests-html.kennethreitz.org/index.html#using-without-requests):

```
import asyncio
import traceback

from pyppeteer import launch
from requests_html import HTML

URL = 'https://secure.louisvuitton.com/eng-gb/checkout/review'
UA = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'


async def fetch(url, browser):
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setUserAgent(UA)

    try:
        await page.goto(url, {'waitUntil': 'load'})
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
    else:
        return await page.content()
    finally:
        await page.close()


async def main():
    browser = await launch(headless=True, args=['--no-sandbox'])

    doc = await fetch(URL, browser)
    await browser.close()

    html = HTML(html=doc)
    print(html.links)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Amazing, I had thought the UA would be the issue here, thank you! I have a whole script written using HTMLSession() session requests, I want to use _async_render for the last request in the project only. Do I need to rewrite the entire script in _async_render to utalise this on the last requests?

Comment: How would I set cookies for the requests?

Comment: You can use [`Page.setCookie`](https://pyppeteer.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html?highlight=cookie#pyppeteer.page.Page.setCookie) to set cookies.